# How to write efficient sql query to select from multiple tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Ok, I have three tables. The parent table is `Listings` and two child tables `Images` and `Tags`.

Here is database schema

**Listings Table**

```
ListingID (PK)      Title                     Images          Tags
1                   Fruits                    1               1
2                   Furniture                 0               0
3                   Electronics               0               0
```

**Images Table**

```
ImageID        ListingID (FK)              ImageName
1              1                           fruits.png
2              1                           fruits_2.png
3              1                           fruits_3.png
```

**Tags**

```
TagID          ListingID (FK)               Tag
1              1                            apple
2              1                            banana
3              1                            melon
```

So I need to select from listings by listingid, and if it has images join images table and if it has tags table.

As output I would like to recieve

For Example I select Listing ID = 1

```
Title            Images                                    Tags
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fruits           fruits.png|fruits_2.png|fruits_3.png      apple|banana|melon
```

Keep in mind the `Listing` table has 100K hits per day. So we need to eliminate row locking

If you have better idea how select from those 3 tables please share with me example.

Comment: I would use three simple queries, one for each table with a where clause `ListingID = 1`. Then I would use the result sets on the client side to build whatever presentation is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
select p.Title, 
stuff((select ', ' + i.ImageName from Images i where i.ListingID = p.ListingID for xml path('')),1,2,'') as Images,
stuff((select ', ' + t.Tag from Tags t where t.ListingID = p.ListingID for xml path('')),1,2,'') as Tags
from Listing p
```

For further reference on the possible options to achieve your goal see http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

BUT I would recommend using 3 simple `SELECT`s and building the needed strings client-side...

Comment: okay. What about if I use 3 simple select in stored procedure and return necessary result? will be it efficient enough?

Comment: that depends on several aspects (the indexes, read/write ratio regarding these tables etc.)... thus hard to say without hard facts... just try both methods and measure them with your real DB and data... and check out the link I just added, it describes several methods to do this with a discussion on pro/con for each...

Answer (score 3):

You can also do

```
SELECT l.Title, i.ImageName, t.Tag FROM
    Listings l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Images i ON l.ListingID = i.ListingID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t ON l.ListingID = t.ListingID
WHERE l.ListingID = 1
```

You will have to massage the produces resultset, but in my work I prefer to separate the pure SQL from application logic.

Comment: This is how I would do it as well.  You can use a simple foreach or LINQ to build your results set up.  The goal is to leverage the database engine to build the data and get it back as quickly as possible - then manipulate the data in memory for the UI presentation.  This is how the MVC / MVVM patterns work.